# emgucv on windows 7 64bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, emgucv

when im running emgu on visual studio development server i get this error:

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8007000B)
```

but when i running debug on local iis web server it works fine.
it happen on the first code line of emgu that im using:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imagePath);
```

this line bind the file in the emgu dll

i allready try to compile emgu on 86 and 64 target and moved those dlls to my project but it didnt make any diffrente still i couldnt run my project on the development server

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile to x86 and enable 32 bit in the server iis: App pool -> advanced settings -> enable 32-bit applications

Comment: iv done that, now like as i describe my problame the development web server give me the error above and the local iis is working,but on my real server its act like the development server error